# Salesforce1 mobile app + Chatter Community

Tags: chatter, salesforce1-app, community

We are a small NPO with a decent sized network.

We have an active chatter instance in our chatter community pages for our partners.

We have no need for an internal chatter feed in our SFDC CRM.

I was very excited when I discovered in the salesforce1 android APP a list of groups that are in the community and NOT in our CRM instance:

[image: Screen shot of community groups on my HTC]

But there is no way I can find for our community users to log into the salesforce1 app (they have a custom page to get in as a partner)

And I cannot see the Community Chatter feed from within Salesforce1 (just my useless CRM feed), but I can see the groups? How and why?

I'm still hoping that community partner users will have access to their chatter feed (and anything else we provide…contacts, ideas etc) via their mobiles in the near future!

I had hoped this would be part of #df13...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using some sort of Single Sign On / oAuth provider for your users to log into your Community?

Comment: no but we did create a custom login page (as the ones given gave us NO ability to customize the look/feel.
https://elele.force.com/kutsalkitap/apex/CommunitiesCustomLogin

but no single sign on/ oAuth stuff used. 

further thoughts?

Comment: perhaps a 2nd (mobile) door could be added for community users??

Comment: but this also brings me back to the puzzle - why on earth are community chatter feeds NOT part of internal chatter feeds?

Comment: to the two initial points:
- I don't see the Community Chatter Groups in salesforce1 app, but I do see the people.
- It would be handy for our customer users to have mobile access: not much of an internet of customers otherwise. To the wider point, it is poor design that the Chatter feeds between CRM and Community are divided. I understand that the licence types don't support this...The issue is that it should, unless there are significant technical issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Salesforce 1 Release Notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_mobile_salesforce1_requirements.htm):

> These user license types aren’t supported:  all communities and portal users, Database.com users, Sites and Site.com users, Data.com users, and Work.com users.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. But :( 

think that will change in the near (or distant) future? Any thoughts on the puzzle i'm having with the Chatter groups being in the salesforce1 app chatter feed even though the groups are part of our community chatter and not internal chatter??